# Why did my icon / avatar thing change

Tags: bug

I used to have a blue icon/avatar, now I have a brown one, with a different pattern. I don't think I did anything that would have changed it. Any idea what happened? I don't feel like myself anymore…

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/236563

Comment: @dlu I think mine has changed too - I'm sure it used to be orange, and now it's brown...

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but it is not obvious to me how it happened. It sounds like this is based entirely on my e-mail and that hasn't changed in decades. I did find a nice suggestion for recovering my old avatar via the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @Zaid's icon/avatar changed as well ... he was able to hocus-pocus his old one back through some extraordinary means ... yah, I don't think it was just you guys.